# Phone creates a Wi-Fi network (i.e. WiFi tethering) while being visible on said network. Possible?

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I have a vague concept for a piece of software I want to write, but I'm facing a problem in that I'm not sure this is even possible with the way Android handles creating Wi-Fi hotspots in its current iteration.

Basically, the device needs to create a hotspot, while being present on the hotspot's network and visible to the other devices, since it needs to act as a server. Is this something that's currently possible on Android, or would you need two separate devices, one to create the network and another to connect to it and act as the server?

Comment: I believe that Android does not support ad-hoc networking out of the box, but there is some software out there to do so (though I haven't tried anything myself).  However, isn't the AP normally accessible in a standard setup?  E.g., a router serving pages on `192.168.0.1`.  Have you tried accessing the device from something connected to its hotspot?

Comment: Yeah, I've done some testing in the meantime and the phones can ping each other at the very least. I'll have to set up some servers and see how those fare. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want to implement an intranet server of some sort through witeless hotspot?